# Why would I want to convert an array into an object

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object

I am currently studying a material that introduces the fundamental concepts required to understand REACT and there is a section of the material where there was an example on converting an array into an object.

My question under what circumstance may I need to convert an array into an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common use case is normalizing data structures which is kind of splitting and simplifying large and complex objects. This is often done in databases and makes it easier to update and maintain the data.

If you want to dive deeper, I recommend you to read [this redux example](https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape). You don't need to know redux to understand the idea.

Otherwise you can google it, I am not an expert in the subject and for me it's difficult to summarize it.

Regards.
Dani

Answer (score 0):

#### **When to Use Objects**

Objects are used to represent a “thing” in your code. That could be a person, a car, a building, a book, a character in a game — basically anything that is made up or can be defined by a set of characteristics. In objects, these characteristics are called **properties** that consist of a key and a value.

#### **When to Use Arrays**

We use arrays whenever we want to create and store a list of multiple items in a single variable. Arrays are especially useful when creating **ordered collections** where items in the collection can be accessed by their numerical position in the list. Just as object properties can store values of any primitive data type (as well as an array or another object), so too can arrays consist of strings, numbers, booleans, objects, or even other arrays.

I hope that clarifies the circumstance that lead to using each one.